# select multiple images from gallery and display in multiple imageview

Tags: android

I have 3 buttons and three imageview, I want to select image from gallery and display every image into specific imageview, means that the user have three different buttons to select image one by one and display them in different imageview
imageview1, imageview2, imageview3, button1,button2,button3

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(data.getData());
            String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = PhotoLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
                acad_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageList.add(photoPath);


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                }
```

above code for single its work

Answer (score 1):

Try to this code..
make three boolean veriable.

```
var button1 = false
var button2 = false
var button3 = false
```

after that when you click on any button that time update boolean value 
like

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener {
        button1=true
        button2 = false
        button3 = false
    }
```

then when you getting image path that time make if condition..

```
if(button1){

            Bitmap bitmap = PhotoLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
            acad_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }

else if(button2){
 }
```

.. so on.